# Find partition(s) assigned to Kafka stream instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka streaming application that subscribes to many topics and each topic has many partitions. 
When I create the application topology and start it, do I know what partitions of what topics are assigned to current instance of my application? I want to know this independent of any records are processed or not by this instance yet.

I know when I get a record, that time I can do `processorContext.partition()` and `processorContext.topic()` to get partition/ topic information of current record being processed. But I am not looking for that.

I am looking for an equivalent of `KafkaConsumer.assigment` on kafka streams side.

I also tried the following code but I get size of s as 0.

```
<Prepare builder and sconfig>
kafkaStream = new KafkaStreams (builder, sconfig);
kafkaStream.start ();
Collection<StreamsMetadata> s = kafkaStream.allMetadata();
System.out.println("StreamsMetadata: size is " + s.size());
for (StreamsMetadata m : s) {
    Set<TopicPartition> tp = m.topicPartitions();
    System.out.println  ("TopicPartition: " + tp.toString());
}
```

Comment: Use case question: why do you need this information in your app?

Comment: I wanted to elect one leader instance out of my app's many instances. An instance with partition 0 of a topic assigned to it will act as leader and perform some special tasks. Wanted to avoid zookeeper/ other infra if possible.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer (Nov 2020):**

> When I create the application topology and start it, do I know what partitions of what topics are assigned to current instance of my application?

If I understand correctly, you can do this as follows. In your application instance, use `KafkaStreams#localThreadsMetadata()` to get the `ThreadMetadata` for all local stream threads (of that app instance). `ThreadMetadata` contains `TaskMetadata` for all active and standby tasks on that stream thread. `TaskMetadata` has a method `topicPartitions()` to get the input topic partitions.

**Old, outdated answer:** There is no existing API in Kafka Streams that exposes this information as far as I know. It is possible to get this information from the Kafka consumer (which is used by Kafka Streams), but it is not exposed in Kafka Streams.

Comment: Can I use ConsumerRebalanceListener with kafka streams?

Comment: I don't think so. The constructor of the `KafkaStreams` class (https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html)  allows you to provide a `KafkaClientSupplier` (https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaClientSupplier.html), but I don't see a way to pass a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` (https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html) all the way to `KafkaConsumer#subscribe()`.

Comment: Sad :/ So, after year passed, still no news about knowing which kafka partitions are assigned to instance by using kafka streams?

Comment: It seems possible today, I updated my answer with instructions.